# Creating An 'NSTimer' in a singleton class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an 'NSTimer' that i want to be able to run whenever i switch to a different view controller. i have a singleton class created and it has this code in it. .H first then .M

```
//  ApplicationManager.h
//  License
//
//  Created by Connor Gosell on 7/31/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Connor Gosell. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface ApplicationManager : NSObject{
NSTimer *ticker;
}

+(ApplicationManager*) instance;



@end
```

**Now The .M File**

```
//  ApplicationManager.m
//  License
//
//  Created by Connor Gosell on 7/31/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Connor Gosell. All rights reserved.
//
#import "ApplicationManager.h"
@implementation ApplicationManager
static ApplicationManager* appMgr = nil;

+(ApplicationManager*) instance
{
@synchronized([ApplicationManager class])
{
    if(!appMgr)
    {
        appMgr = [[self alloc] init];
    }

    return appMgr;
}
}
return nil;
//}


+(id) alloc
{
@synchronized([ApplicationManager class])
{
    NSAssert((appMgr == nil), @"Only one instance of singleton class may be    instantiated.");
    appMgr = [super alloc];
    return appMgr;
}
}

-(id) init
{
if(!(self = [super init]))
{
    [self release];
    return nil;
}

return self;
}
```

**Now The View Controller.H File**

```
//  ViewController.h
//  License
//
//  Created by Connor Gosell on 7/2/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Connor Gosell. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ApplicationManager.h"
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{

IBOutlet UILabel *time;
NSTimer *ticker;
}

- (IBAction)start;
- (IBAction)reset;


- (void)showActivity;


@end
```

**Now The ViewController.M file**

```
//  ViewController.m
//  License
//
//  Created by Connor Gosell on 7/2/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Connor Gosell. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ApplicationManager.h"
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction) start
{
[[ApplicationManager instance]ticker ]:[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0    target:[ApplicationManager Class]selector:@selector(showActivity) userInfo:nil    repeats:YES];
}

-(IBAction)reset
{
[[ApplicationManager instance]ticker: invalidate];
time.text = @" 0:00";
}

-(void) showActivity
{
int currentTime = [time.text intValue];
int newTime = currentTime + 1;
time.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", newTime];
}




- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
/*-(IBAction) start
{
[[ApplicationManager instance] setTicker:[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0   target:self    ``selector:@selector(showActivity) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]];
}

-(IBAction) reset
{
[[[ApplicationManager instance] ticker] invalidate];
time.text = @" 0:00";
}

-(void) showActivity
{
int currentTime = [time.text intValue];
int newTime = currentTime + 1;
time.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", newTime];
}

*/
```

What my problem is is that when i try to run the app on my iphone, it comes back with the errors: no visible @interface declares the selector 'ticker' 
and: use of undeclared identifier 'invalidate'
both of these errors occur in the Viewcontroller.M file on the IBActions start and reset
i cannot seem to find a solution to these errors. any solutions?

Comment: You have a lot of code, but you don't seem to have a question.

Comment: @Caleb added some more information. was looking through xcode to find it! thanks for the heads up

Comment: `[[ApplicationManager instance]ticker: invalidate];` what do you think this colon means ?

Comment: You have declared the ivar `ticker`, but you have not declared an interface to it... (either a method or @property)

Comment: @A-Live it tells the computer the line is complete?

Comment: @Gosell1 colon is a `:`, `;` is a semicolon.

Comment: The C++/Java equivalent of `[[ApplicationManager instance] ticker:invalidate]` is `ApplicationManager::instance()->ticker( invalidate )`

Comment: You really want `ApplicationManager::instance()->ticker()->invalidate()`, which is `[[[ApplicationManager instance] ticker ] invalidate ]`

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but it seems to me that your fundamental problem is not knowing Objective-C syntax. I would recommend learning the language through some lesson books or tutorials, so then you can concern yourself with actually building an application.

Comment: @Chuck and what tutorial would you suggest be best for me?

Answer (score 3):

> no visible @interface declares the selector 'ticker'

You're trying to call a method that doesn't exist:

```
[[ApplicationManager instance]ticker ]
```

That's equivalent to this:

```
[[ApplicationManager instance] ticker]
```

Do you see a method named `-ticker` in ApplicationManager.h? I don't. Perhaps you meant to declare that ivar as a property or something? The rest of the line is sufficiently confused that I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

> use of undeclared identifier 'invalidate'

```
[[ApplicationManager instance]ticker: invalidate]
```

That line really doesn't even make any sense. I think you *meant* something like:

```
[[ApplicationManager instance].ticker invalidate];
```

but that won't work either because, as described above, there's currently no `ticker` property or method declared in ApplicationManager.h.

Also, *why* are you creating this singleton in the first place? All you've got there is a timer, and a timer isn't the sort of thing that you need to access from many places (not that that's a good justification for a singleton either). Get rid of the singleton baloney, instantiate the timer in your view controller, and be happy with simpler, more maintainable code.

Comment: when i instantiate the timer in the view controller, then leave to go to a different view, then come back to the view again, the timer isnt continuing to run.

Comment: @Gosell1, the timer isn't running because you're probably not coming "back to the view again", you're creating a new instance. You need to move back and forth between the view controllers in such a way that the one with the timer isn't deallocated when you move away from it.